# Create new Isotope item and insert foreign content

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, jquery-isotope, packery

I am currently working on a website in Wordpress. I have reached a point that is outside my understanding. I am using Isotope to create and filter my work on the main side of my website. Now, I would like to show a quick preview of the work if the viewer clicks on it. I thought about to insert a new isotope item after the selected work, but my grid falls apart every time I try or the work appears behind the grid.

```
    <h1>Isotope - packery layout mode</h1>
<div class="container">
<div class="thumbs masonry">


  <div class="project small"></div>
  <div class="project small "></div>
  <div class="project small"></div>
     <div class="project small second">
    <div class="title">Project 02</div>
    <div class="slide-show"><ul class="slides">
<li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; display: list-item;"><img src="slide_01.jpg"></li>
<li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative;"><img src="slide_02.jpg"></li>
<li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative;"><img src="slide_03.jpg"></li>
<li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative;"><img src="slide_04.jpg"></li>
</ul></div>
    <div class="description">orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam</div>
    </div>
  <div class="project small"></div>
  <div class="project small"></div>
  <div class="project small"></div>
  <div class="project small"></div>
  <div class="project small"></div>
  <div class="project small"></div>
  <div class="project small">hello</div>
</div>
</div>
```

my css:

```
.thumbs.masonry:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;

}
#content .project.small{    
    width: 22.7%;
    height: auto;
    display: block; 
    margin: 0 2% 20px 0;    
    padding-bottom: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;        
}

#content .project.small.width2{ 
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;  
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

#content .project.small img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;   
}

#content .project.small .title {
    display: none;  
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;    
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0.917em;     
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.1em;
    background: transparent url(images/black_alpha_50.png); 
}

#content .project.small.selected .title{
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}

#content .project.small .title span{
    padding: 12px 17px 12px 17px;
    display: block;
}
```

javascript:

```
var container = jQuery('.thumbs.masonry');
        var colW = container.width() * 0.2475;      
        container.isotope({ 
        animationEngine: 'jquery',  
        resizable: false,
        layoutMode: 'packery',
        packery: {
            //columnWidth: colW
}
```

and

```
function gridResize() { 
    // update columnWidth on window resize
    var container = jQuery('.thumbs.masonry');
    var colW = container.width() * 0.2475;  
    container.isotope({
        resizable: false,
        packery: {
            //columnWidth: colW
        }
    });         
}
```

I already tried it out with codepen.io: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogwEJO
The red square would be the selected work in big. That one works.

I tried to do exactly the same in Wordpress but the red square always disappears.

What I would like help getting to work is implementing my idea. Maybe there is another solution.

Can anyone help me out with this ?
I am really grateful for any advice.

Thanks in advance.

- brig

Answer (score 0):

Use `layout` as an option after you click on an element and you apply a class with the new size, there is an example here: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#layout